# 400 error for api call in react redux working fine in an example

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

- I am trying to learn react redux api call
- so I took an example and implemented in stackblitz but I am getting the below error
  GET https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?%20%20%20%20%20%20%20source=bbc-news&apiKey=c39a26d9c12f48dba2a5c00e35684ecc 400 (Bad Request)
- can you tell me how to fix it
- providing my code and stackblitz below
  https://medium.com/@lavitr01051977/basic-react-redux-app-with-async-call-to-api-e478e6e0c48b

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-realworld-4ldsnt?file=components/ChannelsField.js

```
export function fetchPosts(channel) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestPosts());
    return fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v1/articles? 
      source=${channel}&apiKey=${MY_API_KEY}`)
      .then(
      response => response.json(),
      error => console.log('An error occurred.', error),
    )
      .then((json) => {
        dispatch(receivedPosts(json));
      },
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: Is MY_API_KEY set as a variable in your code?

Comment: @Samrodev hey can you update in my stackblitz its so confusing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your request has extra spaces (%20) between ? and source which is causing the 400 bad request. Change your function to the following and it should work:

```
export function fetchPosts(channel) {
   return function (dispatch) {
      dispatch(requestPosts());
      return fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=${channel}&apiKey=${MY_API_KEY}`)
         .then(response => response.json(),
            error => console.log('An error occurred.', error),
         )
         .then((json) => {
            dispatch(receivedPosts(json));
         },);
   };
}
```

Here is the same GET request without the spaces:

```
https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&apiKey=c39a26d9c12f48dba2a5c00e35684ecc
```

Comment: hey I updaTED BUT STILL i AM FACING THE ERRORS https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-realworld-j95tpu?file=actions/index.js

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `TopNews`.

Comment: @doadhdoadh It looks like the request is working now, but TopNews is getting an error. Change import { NewsItem } from '../components/NewsItem' to import NewsItem from '../components/NewsItem'

Comment: Here is the updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-realworld-esdynq?file=containers%2FTopNews.js

Comment: can you let me know what changes you made

Comment: @doadhdoadh the only change needed was changing the import statement for NewsItem in TopNews. That and the above change for the request in my answer

Comment: hey can you tell me why changed import

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax since you export NewsItem as default you should not de-reference it with { }